# What exchanges offer demo accounts?

Tags: exchanges

I'm having a hard time trying to find exchanges with demo accounts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had tried here before: https://hitbtc.com/

Comment: @pebwindkraft I tried it also but I had no luck, the prices were way off (like $2000 for BTC/USD) and when I made a trade it would only show it was filled, but i couldn't see any actual trade P/L